# Update the value of sublist where match the key in python?

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

Consider the following nested list:

```py
nested_list = [[1, "adam", 20],
               [2, "lucy", 40],
               [3, "mary", 50]]
```

I would like to do the following conditions for example:
Search '3' keyword, if it is found then check second element is "mary", then update third element.

Pseudo:

```
if '3' is found in nested_list then
    if index[1] == "mary" then
        index[2] = 50 + 10 (update)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a spot on Pseudocode, that we can directly change to code. You have the basic idea, iterate through `nested_list` check if the first element in any of the lists are equal to `3`. Then we need to check the second index and see if that is equal to `mary`. If both tests pass, we need to update the last element in the list.

**code**

```
nested_list = [[1,"adam", 20],[2, "lucy", 40],[3, "mary",50]]
for lists in nested_list:
    if lists[0] == 3 and lists[1] == 'mary':lists[2] += 10
```

**input**

```
[[1,"adam", 20],[2, "lucy", 40],[3, "mary",50]]
```

**output**

```
[[1, 'adam', 20], [2, 'lucy', 40], [3, 'mary', 60]]
```

Comment: `index[2]` is supposed to equal `50 + 10`. `index[2]` is `50`. Maybe it should be `lists[2] += 10` not `+= 50 + 10`?

Comment: Oh true, I just assumed user wanted ```50+60+list[2]```